# Particles system use cache external don't work

Tags: particles, baking

I have some problem with local disk cache when i bake particles system.

It seems that it does not work since version 2.8 :

https://developer.blender.org/T68436

I have still same problem :

[image] [image]

It's just a test to try to get it working.

Any solution ?

Thx all

Comment: Ah yes I hadn't thought of making an abc, this will do for what I have to do, thx you.

Comment: I moved my comment to Answer so it can be used for duplications.

Answer (score 0):

There is not an issue with saving in local disk (in term of cache saved in the same directory as blend file). There is an issue assign any other path ... sadly yes ... bug still persists ...

Workaround – It depends on your needs, but you can try export as .abc (**Alembic**) format.