# Importing cache files in blender

Tags: particles, baking, cache

I'm working on a particle simulation and have cached all frames, then enabled "Disk cache" and found the folder with the cache files.
However, when I then select "external cache" and select the folder to use these files, it either tells me "no valid data to read" or "4 points found", which ends up only displaying 4 particles, instead of all 40.

How can i properly import cache files without this happening?

If I use the regular cache (not files), it looks like this:

[image: Settings menu]

[image: Result]

If I use the files I *just* baked, it looks like this:

[image: Settings]

[image: Result]

I need to bake the animation in a separate file before loading it in the main file, so I can't just use the "regular" bake without cache files.

Comment: Duplicated https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/279518

Comment: The "solution" (more of a workaround) on that page doesn't work for me, since the particles would be imported as objects instead of particles, which would add many unnecessary polygons to the scene, which I can't afford in an already large scene.

Comment: Alembic comes with particles saved as animated vertices, so you just instance particle object in the similar way particle system does, right? So I don't think it will enlarge your scene radically. If you didn't succeed (simple test plain with particles) share this sample file, so I can check. Thanks

Comment: Doing that results in the rotation of the particles to be lost, since the animated vertices seem to not save the particle rotation

Comment: Yes, rotation is lost. From your screen it looks like you want to instance a Sphere shape so I didn't care about rotation. If you need to use particle's cache, than your only one chance due the bug (mentioned and persisting in the first comment) is to move cache folder with blend file (keep the same directory).

Comment: Those cubes were only a placeholder, the rotation is extremely important for the final particle system.
The "regular" cache also doesn't persist between sessions, so even if I could keep it in the same file, I would have to re-bake all systems every time I re-launch Blender.

Keeping the same directory also doesn't work, since I would have to first import the cache directory in the new file, which causes the same bug mentioned above.

Comment: can you tell me how did you do to fix the problem? I have the same question now, I cached 300 frames and i can find them in my computer, but when I selected external, only displaying 9 particles. thank you.

Comment: Hi, as I said in my answer below, you just can't. (at least afaik)
I opted to import the particles as objects, which massively slowed down my scene and increased render time, but it was either that, or no particles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again, after tinkering around with this I found out that Blender falls short again.
In short - you can't.
You have to import the particles as objects, massively increasing the polycount in your scene or it just doesn't work.